# ubuntu 18.04 hp printer 2600 not working

Tags: networking

I have a wireless hp deskjet 2655 all in one printer.  I can not get it to connect.  I have looked in settings, printer and it says, "Sorry, the system printing services doesn't seem to be available"
What do I need to do to fix this.

Comment: I do not see exact 2655 model on [HPLIP site](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). Are you sure with model number?

Comment: yes i am sure that is what it is.  i've used 2600 model.

Comment: ok now how do I do this kind of new to this

Comment: sir this is what I get with some errors:       Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-imaging'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
Would you like to retry installing the missing package(s) (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? n
warning: Some HPLIP functionality might not function due to missing package(s).

Comment: Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes gtk2-engines-pixbuf'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes xsane'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
\Gtk-Message: 16:51:45.167: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.


RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS
-----------------------------
OK


RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------

Comment: /Gtk-Message: 16:51:46.948: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.      that is the final part of this.

Comment: Please don't use comments to show us terminal output, add the output to your question instead for 2 reasons: relevant information is in one place, readability.

Answer (score 0):

Sir here is what happened when I tried to install hplip 3.18.7.

rick@rick-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get purge hplip hplip-data hplip-doc hplip-gui hpijs-ppds \libsane-hpaio printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
[sudo] password for rick: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'hplip' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'hplip-data' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'hplip-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libsane-hpaio' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'printer-driver-hpcups' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'printer-driver-hpijs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'hpijs-ppds' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'hplip-gui' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
rick@rick-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip/
rick@rick-System-Product-Name:~$ 
rick@rick-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
rick@rick-System-Product-Name:~$ wget https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hplip/hplip/3.18.7/hplip-3.18.7.run
--2018-10-04 11:32:29--  https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hplip/hplip/3.18.7/hplip-3.18.7.run
Resolving kent.dl.sourceforge.net (kent.dl.sourceforge.net)... 212.219.56.185
Connecting to kent.dl.sourceforge.net (kent.dl.sourceforge.net)|212.219.56.185|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24310927 (23M) [application/x-makeself]
Saving to: ‘hplip-3.18.7.run.1’

hplip-3.18.7.run.1  100%[===================>]  23.18M  1.17MB/s    in 20s

2018-10-04 11:32:50 (1.15 MB/s) - ‘hplip-3.18.7.run.1’ saved [24310927/24310927]

rick@rick-System-Product-Name:~$ sh hplip-3.18.7.run
Creating directory hplip-3.18.7
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.18.7 Self Extracting Archive................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.18.7)
HPLIP Installer ver. 5.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Installer log saved in: hplip-install_Thu-04-Oct-2018_11:33:19.log

\
note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press  to accept the default.
|Gtk-Message: 11:33:23.643: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
/Gtk-Message: 11:33:23.861: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

### INSTALLATION MODE

Automatic mode will install the full HPLIP solution with the most common options.
Custom mode allows you to choose installation options to fit specific requirements.

Please choose the installation mode (a=automatic*, c=custom, q=quit) : a

### INTRODUCTION

This installer will install HPLIP version 3.18.7 on your computer.
Please close any running package management systems now (YaST, Adept, Synaptic, Up2date, etc).

### DISTRO/OS CONFIRMATION

Distro appears to be Ubuntu 18.04.

Is "Ubuntu 18.04" your correct distro/OS and version (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y

Initializing. Please wait...

### ENTER USER PASSWORD

Please enter the sudoer (rick)'s password:

### INSTALLATION NOTES

Enable the universe/multiverse repositories. Also be sure you are using the Ubuntu "Main" Repositories. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more information.  Disable the CD-ROM/DVD source if you do not have the Ubuntu installation media inserted in the drive.

Please read the installation notes. Press  to continue or 'q' to quit:

### SECURITY PACKAGES

AppArmor is installed. 
AppArmor protects the application from external intrusion attempts making the application secure

Would you like to have this installer install the hplip specific policy/profile (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y

### RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS

OK

### MISSING DEPENDENCIES

Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional
cups                 base                 REQUIRED
Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y

### INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)

### CHECKING FOR NETWORK CONNECTION

Network connection present.

### RUNNING PRE-PACKAGE COMMANDS

sudo dpkg --configure -a (Pre-depend step 1)
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes -f (Pre-depend step 2)
sudo apt-get update (Pre-depend step 3)
OK

### DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION

Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
/Gtk-Message: 11:39:34.337: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.

### RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS

OK

### RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES

\Gtk-Message: 11:39:35.994: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
rick@rick-System-Product-Name:~$